# Why can't I set up a DB with Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

```
//jshint esversion:6



const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/fruitsDB", {useUnifiedTopology: true,useNewUrlParser:true});


const fruitSchema = new mongoose.Schema( {
  name: String,
  rating: Number,
  review: String
});

const Fruit = mongoose.model("Fruit",fruitSchema);

const fruit = new Fruit({
  name:"Apple",
  rating:7,
  review:"Great Fruit ! 10/10"
});

fruit.save();
```

The error I have is my program goes to the next command line and then nothing happens, It just freezes

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Can you explain what problem are you having?

Comment: do you have mongoose installed in the folder your in?

Comment: @RiteshKumarGupta When I run node app.js nothing happens on the next line, I did mongod first then mongo and then run node app.js.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The script is working fine, the problem is that `fruits.save()` returns a promise you need to attach a `then` and a `catch` function to further process.

```
fruit
  .save()
  .then(() => {
    console.log('object was saved');
  })
  .catch(console.error)
  .finally(() => {
    mongoose.disconnect();
  });
```

Or you can use async/await

```
try {
  await fruit.save()
} catch (err) {
   // process the error
}
```

> The script is hanging because you do not close the mongo connection.